# What are "Branch indexing" activities in Jenkins BlueOcean

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I'm setting a Multi-Branch pipeline in jenkins blue ocean. Everything is starting to work nice.

One thing I've noticed is that once a while, I get an execution of the job named: "Branch indexing" running.

My build contains some heavy unit testing and code coverage, that take ~4h30 to be executed, so having this job randomly executed 2 times is not really good(not even taking in account that we have 6-8 active branches, so it would mean that the executions will only stacks.

So:

1) What are those executions?
2) Is this absolutely required? 
3) Can I disable it?

Comment: Branch indexing discovers new or deleted branches. In the job configuration (Branch Sources > Property strategy), you can activate _Suppress automatic SCM triggering_, which will not automatically build new branches.

Comment: But this is not a new branch, I'm talking about `develop` that have been build 2h before it has been triggered.

Comment: And it says something like "triggered by branch indexing"?

Comment: The other builds have the name of the last commit. This one has just "Branch indexing" as title, so I guess.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue, trying to disable this "Branch Indexing". I asked a Q here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334258/how-to-disable-branch-indexing

Comment: @five_dollar_shake unfortunately no :(

Comment: It's probably this `Scan Organization Triggers` or `Child Scan Triggers`, from the explanation, it said `This trigger allows for a periodic fallback, but when necessary. If no indexing has been performed in the specified interval, then an indexing will be scheduled.`

Answer (score 2):

In Jenkins, we can create a stage to abort branch indexing.

```
stage('Branch indexing: abort') {
            when {
                allOf {
                    triggeredBy cause: "BranchIndexingCause"
                    not { 
                        changeRequest() 
                    }
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Branch discovered by branch indexing"
                    currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS' 
                    error "Caught branch indexing..."
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're explaining what the 'branch indexing' is though?